# Eigenvalues of a matrix and GMRES

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

From Trefethen's NLA:

> $A$ is a matrix whose singular values are 1 but whose eigenvalues are the $m$th roots of unity that surround the origin. Hence GMRES requires $m$ steps for convergence and CGN takes 1 step.

Am I to believe that GMRES converges in a number of steps equal to the number of distinct eigenvalues of the system? If so, why?

For instance if I had a $n \times n$ matrix $A$ with $\sqrt{n}$ eigenvalues then would I be correct in saying that GMRES converges within $\sqrt{n}$ iterations?

Comment: It is true that CGN would in that case finish in 1 iteration. But it is a very special family of matrices that all eigenvalues are equally distributed on the unit circle. I wonder if they are not even "the same" (in all important algebraic aspects) as the permutation matrices so you can just permute them and multiply and you have the inverse right away.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the statement you have however it is misleading.

> Am I to believe that GMRES converges in a number of steps equal to the
>   number of distinct eigenvalues of the system? If so, why?

No, if you look at how GMRES is designed it is based on the Arnoldi algorithm. We want the following.

It says let $ \mathcal{K}_{n}$ be the $m \times n $ Krylov matrix and our problem is to find a vector $c \in \mathbb{C^{n}}$ such that

$$  \| A \mathcal{K}_{n} c - b  \| \tag{1} $$

The Krylov method is numerically unstable because of linear independence in the columns so you use the $QR$ method it showed before

$$  \| A Q_{n} y - b\| \tag{2} $$

then this becomes

$$  \| Q_{n+1}\hat{H}_{n} y - b \| \tag{3} $$

$$ \| \hat{H}_{n}y  - Q_{n+1}^{*} b \| \tag{4} $$

this finally is

$$ \| \hat{H}_{n}y - \| b \| e_{1} \| = \| r_{n} \|  \tag{5} $$

So at each step, we are checking $ \| r_{n}\|$  which is the residual. The number of steps required is based on the condition number of the matrix as well. The relationship is given here

$$ \kappa(A) = \frac{\lambda_{max}}{\lambda_{\min}} \tag{6}$$

So, it is related to the number of eigenvalues because if there are not many eigenvalues then it doesn't have to find any. All it is doing is constructing a low-rank approximation through an eigenbasis.

Comment: So if I have an $nm \times nm$ matrix and $(n-1)m$ eigenvalues are equal to 1 then we can not say that GMRES will converge within m+1 iterations? hmmm. I always thought that the number of iterations was dependent on the number of distinct eigenvalues.

Comment: It is dependent on the number of distinct eigenvalues however it is also dependent on the conditioning the matrix and the tolerance you set. If all your eigenvalues are 1 and the other eigenvalue is $.000001$  that is different from it being $0.1$

Comment: There is an example on page 272 about the convergence rate with different eigenvalues that shows this. If you look on page 273. The difference is startling.